# hadoop command to find namenode in a node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

I tried

Steps

> ```
> - Login into particular node
> - and execute the command jps
> ```

Result

```
5144 JobTracker
4953 NameNode
5079 SecondaryNameNode
5216 Jps
```

this is working fine, but I what know any other command to find namenode in a node

Comment: Specifically I what know the NameNode service is running in a node or not

Answer (score 1):

Information about Namenode, Datanode and Secondary Namenode processes can be seen using the command:

```
ps -fu hdfs
```

Information about ResourceManager, NodeManager processes can be seen using the command:

```
ps -fu yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command :
ps -ef |grep Namenode

to see the namenode process .This would let you know if a particular java process namenode is running.

Comment: I need like this `service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status`  but it's not working

Comment: `service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager status` this command is working in datanode .. but `service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status` it's not working

Comment: nodemanager and datanode are different stories, nodemanager is at Yarn part while datanode is the HDFS part.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, trying to find the Namenode process should be the first choice. The other ways that might work could be:

1. Try to check if the 50070 port (Namenode web UI) is opened to listen:

   `netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN' | grep 50070`
2. Look into the Namenode settings in hdfs-site.xml under $HADOOP_CONF_DIR